# How to disable auto replies for an outlook email?

Tags: outlook, auto-reply

I am sending mails to an org list with many subscribers and I receive lot of auto replies. How can I disable them from client side or server side ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're getting auto replies from the recipients? If that's the case then you can't disable them as they're being generated by the remote MTA or email client, not from your MTA.

Comment: +1 Gotta use Outlook Inbox Rules.

Comment: How can I create an outlook rule that will delete only those auto replies? I tried creating one that deletes all incoming message with Auto Reply in subject line, this may delete some genuine mails.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. You'll either have to set up an Outlook rule and risk losing some legitimate emails or don't set up a rule and manually deal with all of the auto-replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange, there is a setting, specific to the version, that allows you to block system messages (OOF, mailbox full, NDR, etc)  from being forwarded to the Internet. You'll need to check the docs for the setting specific to your version.

Comment: But that setting will impact the whole company? I just wish to block auto replies to me.

Comment: That setting is for outbound replies, not inbound.

Comment: Yeah, I misread that.